# Change color of each point in scatter plot sequentially

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, scatter-plot

I am new to Matlab, I was trying to you scatter plot to plot 4 points in an axes.

for example

```
x = [0;0;1;-1];
y = [1;-1;0;0];
scatter(x,y);
```

what I wanted to do was to change the color of one coordinate in the above plot continuously in clock wise direction

[image]

Like the above pic.

If not is there another way I can do so?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to plot each point separately, get a handle to each, and then change their `'color'` property sequentially in a loop:

```
%// Data
x = [-1;0;1;0]; %// define in desired (counterclockwise) order
y = [0;1;0;-1];
color1 = 'g';
color2 = 'r';

%// Initial plot
N = numel(x);
h = NaN(1,N);
hold on
for n = 1:N
    h(n) = plot(x(n), y(n), 'o', 'color', color1);
end
axis([-1.2 1.2 -1.2 1.2]) %// set as desired

%// Change color of one point at a time, and restore the rest
k = 0;
while true
    k = k+1;
    pause(.5)
    n = mod(k-1,N)+1;
    set(h(n), 'color', color2);
    set(h([1:n-1 n+1:end]), 'color', color1);
end
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can add a 4th argument to `scatter` in order to set the color (the 3rd argument sets the size, you can leave it empty):

```
col = lines(4); % create 4 colors using the 'lines' colormap
scatter(x,y,[],col);
```

You can use some other colormaps (type `doc colormap` in Matlab for more details), or just enter some vector of numbers to use the current colormap.

**Edit** I've just realized you wanted to change the color of only one point; you can do it with (for example) `col = [2 1 1 1]`.